# Mainframe VSE configuration questions for a new Systems Admin for VSE

Tags: mainframe

I am not new to mainframe but I am new to the System Administrator side of configuring a mainframe. I have mostly been on the production control/computer operations side of the Mainframe. I was wondering if any one can share with my some resources for user guides on z/VSE. Through my research I have found plenty of documentation telling me what pieces are. But, I have been unsuccessful and finding documentation that can show me how to do things. I have listed some current asks that I am having trouble figuring out.

- Adding space to POWER queues
- Changing account name on MSHP file
- Adding tape server program
- Adding `prd2.gen2` to the system

Any help with resources to help me configure or any help on the above 4 tasks is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!